# Codeigniter Undefined Property, or how will my controller stop worrying and learn to love the model

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am following the tutorial from the [Codeigniter website](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html) about making a news section. Right now I am getting an undefined property message on line 13.

Here is my model. **applications/models/articles_model**

```
<?php

class Articles_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_article($slug = False){

        if ($slug === FALSE){

             $query = $this->db->get('articles');
             return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get('articles');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('articles', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

And here is the controller. **applications/controllers/articles.php**

```
<?php

class Articles extends CI_Controller{

    public function __contruct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Articles_model');
    }

    public function index(){

        //Message: Undefined property Articles::Articles_model    
        $data['articles'] = $this->Articles_model->get_article();
        $data['title'] = "Archive";

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('articles/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug){

        $data['articles'] = $this->Articles_model->get_article($slug);

        if(empty($data['articles'])){

            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['articles']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('articles/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

These are all the routes I have setup. **applications/config/routes.php**

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/view/$1';
$route['articles'] = 'articles';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

My database looks like this

```
mysql> describe articles
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug  | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| text  | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have tried using the property with a capital first-letter,`$this->Articles_model`, and not, `$this->articles_model`.

Am I missing something stupid?
If so what is it?
If it's not stupid how can I debug?

**EDIT**

The ouput of print_r, as per comments, did not contain "Articles_model". The first tier thing is over my head, but CTRL-F isn't. Also the Apache logs mention this...

```
[Sun Sep 23 13:19:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_article() on a non-object in /home/noel/dev/web/
ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/application/controllers/articles.php on line 13
```

**EDIT1**

I thought I fixed it, but no, see the comment on my *answer*. For some reason `$this->article_model` is not an object.

Why? I've been to one World Fair, a Picnic and a Rodeo and that's the stupidest thing I ever heard come over a set of earphones. You sure you got today's codes?

Comment: On line 12, just before you get the error.  Do a `print_r($this);`.  In the first tier of object properties (hopefully this isn't over your head, though it may be...) look for "Articles_model".  If you're unsure if it's the first tier, try updating your question with some of the output of `print_r` so we can help you more.

Comment: Done. Updated OP. Thanks. Still no joy.

Comment: This, folks, is how you title a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a closer look and the answer is very simple: Try changing this line:

```
public function __contruct(){
```

to this:

```
public function __construct(){
```

;)

Comment: Well that looks suspect. After I fixed that I found a couple little bugs easily and it works now. Mahalo.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. It was in the routes.php. These lines

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/view/$1';
$route['articles'] = 'articles';
```

I changed to this...

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'Articles/view/$1';
$route['articles'] = 'Articles';
```

And now I get a 404 because my database is empty, as expected. Still don't know why theses rules...

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'
```

from the first tutorial work without "pages"being capitalized. The world will never know...

Comment: Captains Log,  This actually didn't work. False alarm. Still no joy. Suspect chaging routes actually returned 404 because CI couldn't find the controller at all. The journey continues. Why isn't $this->articles_model a model?  **I don't give a hoot in Hell how you do it, you just get me to the Primary, ya hear!**

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding the comments: `print_r($this);` is a very bad idea, as it will only confuse you. `$this` contains almost none of the ci stuff. What you are looking for is `print_r(get_instance());`

Regarding your problem: ci lowercases member names. Change your line to this and your are good to go:

```
$this->articles_model->get_article();
```

Comment: Well, I tried changing the line already that's in the OP. And `print_r(get_instance());` was as confusing as `print_r`, just a huge array barfed onto the page. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry, missed your note about the capitalization. Did you have a close look the outputs of that `print_r`? Your model is not in there?

Comment: I did a CTRL-F to look for it but "Articles_model" only appeared in the error message not the print_r() array.